# simple counting problem causing confusion (foundamental counting principle)

Tags: combinatorics

I'm sorry for the basic question, but I can't figure this out.

Suppose you want to find how many even, non-repeating 3-digit numbers there are.  If you choose the last digit to be non-zero, you have $(8)(8)(5) = 320$ possibilities.  If you choose the last digit to be zero, you have $(9)(8)(5) = 360$ possibilities.  What should I do?

Comment: Choose the ones-place digit first.  Then choose the hundreds-place digit and finally choose the tens-place digit.  Break into cases based on whether in the first step the chosen ones-place digit is a zero or not.  Remember that the hundreds-place digit of a three-digit number cannot be zero.

Comment: By "even" you mean the 3-digit number itself is even, or do you mean that *each digit* is even?

Comment: For the former I got (5)(4)(5) [first two digits must be odd] +(4)(5)(4) [first digit even and nonzero, second digit odd] + (5)(5)(4) [first digit odd second digit even] + (4)(4)(3) [first two digits even first digit nonzero]

Answer (score 2):

If you choose the last digit to be non-zero ($\{2,4,6,8\}$), we have

$$(8)(8)\color{red}{(4)}$$

If you choose the last digit to be zero $\{0\}$, we have

$$(9)(8)\color{red}{(1)}$$

then sum them up.